# Error found while developing games with react

Tags: css, reactjs

I am getting the following error while duilding tic-tac-toe game with react.
"./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: Package exports for 'G:\Nodejs\projectReact\tic-tac-toe\node_modules\colorette' do not define a valid '.' target"

Comment: Do you have cssLoadres configured in webpack ?

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue when I had the latest `colorette` version installed i.e. `1.2.1`. As per my understanding, this version of `colorette` requires Node 14+ while I have Node 13.1. Therefore there are two options to resolve this, either upgrade Node to 14+ version of downgrade `colorette` to its previous version `1.2.0`.

I have not tried upgrading Node as it will effect my other projects so I have just downgraded `colorette` to 1.2.0 and it works fine for my case by using following commands.

To uninstall colorette:

`npm uninstall colorette`

To install colorette version 1.2.0:

`npm install colorette@1.2.0`

Comment: Although this is not exactly related, but there may be cases where some other npm packages would have been using the `colorette` version `1.2.1` in that case that package may also have to be downgraded. Like I have to downgrade `autoprefixer` to `9.8.4` from `9.8.6` as the `9.8.6` version of autoprefixer was using `colorette 1.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem  when using node v 13.1.x  upgrade it to 14.x helped so far using command :
sudo n latest